# Strong orientation graph algorithm with Robbins' theorem

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

I've been asked a question that goes something like this:

> Using depth-first search and Robbins' theorem, design and analyze an efficient algorithm to construct a strong orientation of a given undirected graph G. If none exist, output a bridge in G.

Now, I can prove Robbins' theorem easily, which states that a graph is strongly orientable if and only if it has no bridges (i.e. it is 2-edge-connected). The example given to me is similar to what's given in Robbins' 1939 paper describing his eponymous theorem with the traffic problem and one-way streets. But I'm at a loss as to how to construct this algorithm.

(Well, not *quite* at a loss. What if we did something like this: run DFS, make all black edges one direction, and make all grey edges the other. All the while, test for 2-edge-connectivity for each vertex. This is pure intuition, though, and I'm not sure how one can define a consistent directionality.)

Comment: You might get more insightful answers on [the computer science stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 2):

DFS on an undirected graph yields only tree edges and back edges. Orienting the tree edges from ancestor to descendant allows the root to reach all other nodes. The back edges should be oriented from descendant to ancestor, since the other direction is covered by tree edges. If you find a subtree with no back edges to ancestors of the subtree, then the edge into the subtree is a bridge. Otherwise, there's a path from every node to the root by repeated escaping the current subtree via some edge to an ancestor, making the oriented graph strongly connected.